# HTMLで使用できる、環境依存文字ではない括弧の一覧について

Tags: 文字化け, 文字コード

HTMLで使用できる、環境依存文字ではない括弧の一覧を調べるにはどうすればよいですか？

これまで()を使用していたのですが、足りなくなったので新たな括弧を使用したい。
丸数字は環境依存文字なので使用しないほうがよいと聞いたことがあるのですが、括弧の場合にもありますか？

色々な括弧がありますが、環境依存文字かどうかはどうやって判断すればよいですか？

環境
・UTF-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

けっきょくはブラウジング環境にインストールされているフォントに目的の字体が入っているかどうかなので、

- ASCII の範囲内の文字なら表示できない環境はほぼないだろうと期待できる
- ASCII 範囲外なら、サポートしたいすべての動作環境で表示テストするしかない
- ウェブフォントを利用すればウェブフォントをサポートしている環境なら間違いなく表示できる